# Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly but it's not mscorlib

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this exception message when I try to run my Visual Studio 2013 Web Application:

```
"Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'Bridge, Version=1.0.1.30841, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."
```

I found lots of pages about this attribute moving between 4.0 and 4.5, but I am running .NET 4.6.1, and compiling the assemblies to 4.6.1.  Also, this error is not about mscorlib, it is about an assembly I am building myself, named Bridge.  I don't understand why there is a reference to System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute in my assembly, and I am not sure what I should do to make it stop.  Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bridge" might be a bad name for the assembly.  I have my Bridge in a local NuGet server, so I can use it in several of my projects.  There is a Bridge.NET in one of the NuGet repositories configured for VS 2013 by default.

I think I was updating the other NuGet packages in my solution and hit an "Update All" button.  Since I had a Bridge in my project, and there was a Bridge.NET in the list of updates, the assembly for Bridge.NET was included in my project, unbeknownst to me.  I had cleaned the project and rebuilt, but that hadn't erased the Bridge.NET assembly from the bin folder.  I saw an assembly named Bridge.Html5.dll in the folder that I didn't intend to be there.  I think it was part of the Bridge.NET.  I erased the bin folder, rebuilt, and the project ran.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an assembly referenced to your `Bridge` assembly which targets `net40`. It could be a NuGet package like in this example:

```xml
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net40" />
```

If this is the case update that NuGet package that targets at least `net45`.

FYI: This attribute is needed when you create an extension method in VB.NET.

Here is an example.

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module StringExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsNullOrEmpty(ByVal value As String) As Boolean

        IsNullOrEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Nice idea, but, ... There are no package references to targetFramework="net40" in the packages.config for that assembly, or any of the referenced assemblies in that assembly.  There are no references to CompilerServices in any of the assemblies.  I removed the reference in the Assembly.cs for the project.

Comment: Let me see clearly, what exactly did you remove from Assembly.cs file of which project? Did you remove something from `Bridge`'s Assembly.cs file? And did it solve your issue?

Comment: It did not solve my issue.  I remove the "using CompilerServices" statement from the top of the Assembly.cs file.  There are no places in the Bridge assembly that reference CompilerServices.  I am still getting the error.  This was to remove red herrings, mostly.